# How to use Blobstore Services File upload with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to upload a file to Blobstore with JQuery / Ajax. Is there a possibility of uploading a file to Blobstore with JQuery or Ajax in Java application?

Comment: Of course it can. What have you tried?

Comment: Its,all in the docs. Read them first. In any case the question doesnt seem to make sense since java is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs about the [server side blob upload](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob). Then see the client side: [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: For PHP its working fine ,It would be nice if you share a sample working code for JSP